# Send input /dev/ttyUSB0 get the output

Tags: bash, tty

How can I send input to `/dev/ttyUSB0` and get its output. I'm trying to do this in bash script. Any ideas?

Comment: I've read your question several times and still can't figure out what your trying to achieve. Can you clarify please.

Comment: I will explain it with screen:
`screen /dev/ttyUSB0`
`COMMAND`
`output`
`exit screen`

In such case I can do it with screen but I need a script to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem using pyserial library of python.

http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/